# Creating dummy variables for more than 2 levels

Tags: r, dummy-variable

How do I create dummy variables for more than two levels for categorical data in r? I tried model.matrix but it didn’t work.

Comment: This has been answered several times over at Cross Validated. You could try searching there(and here too).

Comment: Here is an interesting [CV thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/379760/can-a-dummy-variable-take-on-more-than-2-values). It might help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read your coulmn as class `factor`.

Suppose your data is stored in `df` and `categories` has the categories you want to convert to dummies. Then:

```
df$categories <- as.factor(df$categories)
```

You will not see new columns created. The factor class is a shortcut for this kind of task. Try running a regression model like this and you'll see the results.

Comment: Thanks for helping with my question! as.factor works :)

Comment: Good to hear! Vote me up!